# Python: is there any sense to use both multiprocessing and threading (for the same task)?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

If I have an app or function (which can't be split in parts) that works faster multithreaded and also works faster when using multiprocessing, how to start multiple threads in each process?

**edit:**

I figured it's possible with the code like this:

```
class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threads_in_queue, worker_function, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        ...
    def run(self):  # метод должен быть.
        while True:
            ...
            q = self.threads_in_queue.get()
            self.worker_function(q)

threads_in_queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue(maxsize=number_of_threads)

class ProcessClass(...):
    def __init__(self, processes_in_queue):
        ...

    def run(self):
        while True:
            ...
            q = self.processes_in_queue.get()
            threads_in_queue.put(q)

def worker_function(...):
    ...

for i in number_of_threads:
    t = ThreadClass(worker_function, threads_in_queue, arg1, ..., kwarg1=..., ...)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    processes_in_queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

    for i in number_of_processes:
        t = ProcessClass(processes_in_queue)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    for thing_to_queue in things_to_queue:
        processes_in_queue.put(...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible that you could use both multiprocessing and multithreading in the same program; although, that's probably not common. Since the default Python has a global interpreter lock, you might use multiprocessing in order to saturate multiple CPUs or cores, but if you were doing some primary task that also involved a lot of blocking I/O, you might use threading to increase total parallelism and decrease latency.

For example, let's say you were writing a parallel crawler of some variety. Parsing HTML is actually quite CPU intensive in Python, but crawling is primarily network and I/O bound. So you might use multiprocessing to dispatch multiple parallel crawlers in separate processes simultaneously, but then use threading within that process in order to increase the total number of parallel connections you process.

There are probably other examples where combining both would be useful. However, typically when I've written systems similar to this in the past, I've not used the [built-in Python multiprocessing library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) directly but rather just spun up entirely separate processes on the same machine and then used greenlets via the [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) library (which is a form of multithreading) to increase parallelism. I've done this for multiple web services where each process is a serving up requests on a separate port and then you have some form of load balancer point directly at all of the processes. This is a very scalable architecture.

For what it is worth, the Python multiprocessing library, the Python threading library, and the gevent library are almost all identical in their interface, so you can switch pretty seamlessly between all of them.